# httpd - operating source html in compressed format

Tags: httpd, html

For the sake of storage limitation I was wondering if the webpages stored in my open source router firmware could be individually compressed to reduce demand on flash. So index.html would be stored as index.html.gz or something.

I guess this would means having the httpd process decompressing on-the-fly as it's requested by the browser right?

I read up on mod_deflate but (unless I'm reading this wrong) it does compress on-the-go uncompressed source files. My question instead revolves about reducing source pages storage size so I guess it wouldn't help my situation.

Can anybody shed some light on whether this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Typically when you need optimizing at the level of a couple of 100 kB worth of plain text, then I would expect that all your other resources are very constrained as well, I.e, RAM and CPU and using those to counter to your storage limits is likely a bad trade off. But fairly typical is that the  firmware image is compressed and by including your html there it will be too. At boot that will be uncompressed into a RAM disk, costing you ram memory

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with everything you're mentioning and totally agree on the tradeoff. I think I did already get to the conclusion that reducing flash usage and increasing CPU (since these pages are for administration only so used seldom) is somehow the best option for me compare to uncompressing them into RAM. So my OP is still valid.